# CriteriaBuilder and multiple join condition

Tags: java, mysql

Is there any possibility to add more join condidions to be added in ON clause? For example:

```
select * from table t left join second_table st ON t.id = st.id_second AND st.something = 2;
```

My code is:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
Order o;
CriteriaQuery<Documentation> select = builder.createQuery(Documentation.class);
Root<Documentation> u = select.from(Documentation.class);
Join<Documentation, DocumentationUser> dul = u.join("documentationUserCollection", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Comment: No. But you could emulate it with "where st.id_second is null or st.something = 2".

Comment: TBH I need to exactly this query via criteriabuilder `select * from table t left join second_table st ON t.id = st.id_second AND st.something = 2 WHERE st.otherParam is null;`

Comment: And? My answer would be the same. It's not possible. But you may emulate it with `select * from table t left join second_table st ON t.id = st.id_second where (st.id_second is null or (st.something = 2 and st.otherParam is null))`

Comment: This will return wrong record set.

Comment: Why would it? Not saying you're wrong. Just curious to know what would be different from the first query.

Comment: First of all `ON t.id = st.id_second where (st.id_second is null` means totally nothing. Second of all this query suppose to left join second_table only if keys matches and record in second_table has column something with value 2. If not it suppose to fill joined table with null. Your query is joining records using keys and trying to find records which has nulled key (?!?) or column something with value 2 and otherParam null. Totally different queries.

Comment: OK. I just tested i, and you're right, it doesn't select the same rows. My bad. The answer is thus: it's not possible.